# Why is my flutter code not running? I have tried everything but is still not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, spring-webflux, flutter-test

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Scaffold(dirty, state: ScaffoldState#48b2a(tickers:
tracking 2 tickers)):
No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was:
Scaffold
The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "Scaffold ← HomeScreen ← [root]"
No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those
widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above
those widgets.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Scaffold Scaffold:file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/final_project/lib/main.dart:9:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      debugCheckHasMediaQuery. (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:297:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:312:4)
#2      ScaffoldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2739:12)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5007:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4895:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5060:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4617:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4877:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5051:11)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4871:5)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3883:16)
#17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3612:18)
#18     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1195:16)
#19     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1164:5)
#20     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:18)
#21     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2626:19)
#22     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1110:13)
#23     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:945:7)
#24     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:925:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...                      3.4s

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with sound null safety

An Observatory debugger and profiler on AOSP on IA Emulator is available at: http://127.0.0.1:57771/nYUPJbrEd3U=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on AOSP on IA Emulator is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:57771/nYUPJbrEd3U=/
[image: enter image descriptioenter image description heren here]

Comment: May be You are using Scaffold Widget in wrong Place except to MaterialPage Widget.

Comment: You can share your code snippet for quick and better answer

Comment: Okay how do i do that for u
I dont really know how to

Answer (score 0):

```
      class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// below MaterialApp seems to be missing from your code
        return MaterialApp(         
          title: 'DiD Task',
          initialRoute: "/",
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            backgroundColor: AppConstants.appBackGroundColor,
            primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          home: const Splash(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Your HomeScreen inside the MaterailApp widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
```

then Call your Scaffold on HomePage like this

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Your Home Page"),
      ),
      body: Text("Your Body"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
const HomeScreen({key?:key}) :super:(key:key);
@override
state<HomeScreen> createState()=> _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends state<HomeScreen>{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Scafold(
body:Text("write here your Home screen code")
);
```

then pass this screen to you main file in home:HomeScreen